# How to read updated state in react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am learning Redux and trying to Add/View users using redux in my react app.By using 'ref' in react, I am reading the payload(name,account_number) of new user and passing to 'addProfile' action creator onClick of 'Add' button in this way -

**AddView.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { addProfile } from '../actions';

class AddView extends React.Component{

    addValues(){
        return(
            <div>
                Name : <input type="text" value={this.props.profiles.name} ref={el => this.nameValue=el}/> 
                Account Number : <input type="text" value={this.props.profiles.account_number} ref={el => this.accountValue=el}/>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.addProfile(this.nameValue,this.accountValue)}>Add</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                Add Profile
                <br /><br />
                {this.addValues()}

            </div>
        );
    }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { profiles : state.profiles }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addProfile}) (AddView);
```

Now am trying to console log the name,account_number in my action creator but I get html instead of values.

```
export const addProfile = (name, account_number) => {
    console.log(name,account_number)
    return{
        type :'ADD_PROFILE',
        payload : {
            name : name,
            account_number : account_number
        }
    };
}
```

Can anyone please help where I went wrong. Full code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/239j97y36p

Comment: if it is only for debugging, why not using [redux-dev-tools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#redux-devtools-extension) you would have a nive UI with test cases, history and many more features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React refs give you a ref to the dom element, if you just want the value of the input you can get it with `.value`. I would also rename your ref variables then to be accurate like `nameInputRef` and `accountInputRef`.

```
    Name :{" "}
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.props.profiles.name}
      ref={el => (this.nameInputRef = el)}
    />
    Account Number :{" "}
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.props.profiles.account_number}
      ref={el => (this.accountInputRef = el)}
    />
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        this.props.addProfile(this.nameInputRef.value, this.accountNumberRef.value)
      }
    > Add
    </button>
```

You can see full sample adapted from yours here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k3mp28lr3o

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {}
    render() {

        // ref={el => this.nameValue=el} to access input variable 
        // or 
        // use onChange event which fire another dispatcher which mutate profile state since we assign input values to profile state you can use state to get latest values


        //this.props.profiles
        //this.props.onAddProfile()
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    profiles : state.profiles
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      onAddProfile:dispatch(addProfile())
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserProfile);
```

Comment: addProfile should return your action object.

Comment: need example please let me know. will update with example :)

Comment: Yes please.. Am not sure how to use the mapDispatchToProps so please explain the event handling with example code

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the element into the variable during the onclick event.

```
ref={el => this.nameValue=el}
```

You can use a local state to store the value of the while onChange instead of ref

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install redux-thunk --save
```

profile.jsx

```
class Profile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={({ target }) =>
                        this.props.onUsernameUpdated(target.value)
                    }
                    value={this.props.profile.username}
                    placeholder="Username"
                />

                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={({ target }) =>
                        this.props.onAccNumberUpdated(target.value)
                    }
                    value={this.props.profile.accNumber}
                    placeholder="Account Number"
                />

                <button onclick={this.props.onUpdateProfile}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        profile: state.profile
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onUsernameUpdated: username => dispatch(usernameUpdated(username)),
        onAccNumberUpdated: password => dispatch(accNumberUpdated(accNumber)),
        onUpdateProfile: () => dispatch(updateProfile())
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Profile);
```

actions.js

```
export function usernameUpdated(username) { // need reducer to update state profile name
    return {
        type: 'USER_NAME_UPDATE',
        data: username
    }
}

export function accNumberUpdated(accNumber) { // need reducer to update state profile acc number
    return {
        type: 'ACC_NUM_UPDATE',
        data: accNumber
    }
}

export function updateProfile() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => { //thunk magic
        // latest profile after user input
        const profile = getState().profile
    }
}
```